# Nepali / India bioacoustics hiking

Tags: animals, india, nepal

Has anyone recorded animal sounds while trekking the Annapurna trail (Nepal) or in Ladakh (India)? If so, where are the richest acoustic areas?

Comment: I've been lucky enough to have seen Ibex, blue sheep (bharals) and marmots (which are pretty common to be honest) in Leh/Ladakh region. But I'm not sure if anyone would've recorded the sounds of them.

Comment: For what it's worth: rocky, mountainous area's like what I'm imagining when I think of Nepal do carry sounds a decent way. Could be too echoey for good recordings, but I'm not a sound technician...

Comment: Unlikely to record animal sounds in Ladakh, The animals there are all solitary in nature and not very noisy by default. You'd be lucky to observe them from a distance.

Comment: What if a recorder was left (passive acoustic monitoring - PAM) without a human around? Since there would not be anyone to disturb shy animals, they would behave normally. Recorders can last for months at a time, so as long as an animal made a sound in the general area it would be recorded. And many times these sorts of PAM studies have discovered that animals we used to think were quiet were actually very vocal. Even Jacques Cousteau famously called the ocean silent, which we learned later it is most definitely not.

Comment: @Kerri Yes, that will almost definitely work. Use your best skills in placement of the devices - it actually isn't easy. You can also use cameras to determine where the creatures move. Maybe even drones (check their legality in that part of India).